# How to send php variable in an html form with a given value

Tags: php, html, variables

I have a problem with my PHP code. I'm trying to send a variable to another page. I know how to do it with other variables because I´m giving the value for them in the form. However, what if I have a variable I want to send with a given value (that I gave before)?

In this case, the variable I want to send is called `$Dir`, and it contains the path of a file with some information about an event. I want to send that path to the next page, so it could open it. Here is the code :

```
    <html>
         <body>
            <h1>Select one option...</h1> 
         </body>
        <form action="button2.php" method="post" target="page">
        <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Participate on the event"> 
        <input type="submit" name="Mod" value="Modify my information"> 
        <input type="submit" name="Erase" value="Erase my confirmation"> 
        <input type="submit" name="Info" value="See the event information"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="Dir" value=$Dir"> 
        </form>
        <iframe name="page" src="button2.php"> //llamada al botton.php
        </iframe>
    </html>
```

So the problem I have is that obviously I'm sending Dir with the value `$Dir` while what I want is sending Dir with the value it has (for example, `C:/user/file.txt`). Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Problem**

You are trying to resolve a PHP variable to a file path string in HTML.

**Solution**

You can use `echo` to output the string. [Doc here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

```
<input type="hidden" name="Dir" value="<?php echo $Dir; ?>">
```

Make sure to be careful with this. You are putting a file path in a hidden field but anyone can still see it if they look at the DOM. It might be safer to change this to an ID that you can use to identify which file path you need when this form is submitted and then use that on the server to lookup the correct file path. This would also make it more dynamic.

**Example**

```
$filePathID = 1;

<input type="hidden" name="Dir" value=<?php echo $filePathID; ?>">
```

If you take this route you might handle this on the server like this,

```
if ($_POST['Dir'] == 1) {
    $filePath = "C:/user/file.txt"
}    else   {
    $filePath = "C:/user/otherFile.txt"
}

// Do something with the... $filePath;
```